# Projectile trajectory based on angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, game-physics

In my 3D game (top down shooter), I try to do this:
When you click the mouse button (raycast on point) on a specific area on the map -> a shot was fired from the gun -> the projectile flies in the **direction of the barrel** with a certain path and at the same **distance as the mouse pointer** (but not the direction).
I already have the source code for calculating the projectile trajectory.
Help make the projectile fly in the direction of the barrel, BUT with the **distance shown by the mouseposition** raycast, NOT the mouseposition direction.

[image]

````
```private void FireCannonAtPoint(Vector3 point)
{
    var velocity = BallisticVelocity(point, _angle);

    GameObject projectile = Instantiate(_projectile, _shootPoint.transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = velocity;
}

private Vector3 BallisticVelocity(Vector3 destination, float angle)
{
    Vector3 dir = destination - _shootPoint.transform.position; 
    float height = dir.y;
    dir.y = 0; 
    float dist = dir.magnitude; 
    float a = angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad; 
    dir.y = dist * Mathf.Tan(a); 
    dist += height / Mathf.Tan(a); 

    float velocity = Mathf.Sqrt(dist * Physics.gravity.magnitude / Mathf.Sin(2 * a));
    return velocity * dir.normalized; 
}```
````

Comment: What do you mean by mouseposition raycast and NOT the mouseposition direction?

Comment: If you look at my attached pic : **mouseposition direction** is - line between "turret" and "raycast mouseclick". And **mouseposition raycast** is - bullet flying forward from "turret" (in pic this is red arrow).

Answer (score 0):

Barrel: segment `[turret_end_1, turret_end2]` in 3D, where `turret_end_1` the point on the turret where the bullet leaves it.

Screen: the focal point `F` and the plane of the screen, named `screen_plane`.

```
# From 3D to 2D: projection from 3D space on the screen_plane:
Mouse = [mouse_x, mouse_y] # given on the screen_plane
B1 = project_on_screen_plane(turret_end_1)
B2 = project_on_screen_plane(turret_end_2)

# Calculations in 2D, i.e. on the screen_plane
U = B1-B2
U = ( dot_product(Mouse-B1, U) / dot_product(U, U) ) * U
U = B1 + U # this is the point you are looking for on the screen


# From 2D back to 3D: connect the focal point with the point U on the screen plane
# to form a line and find its intersection point in 3D with the line B1 B2
# aligned with the turret.
# line through F with directing vector Vector_from_F_to(U)
# line through B1 with directing vector B1-B2

V = intersect( F,  Vector_from_F_to(U),  B1,  B1-B2 ) # the point you are looking for in 3D
```